# Rmd loads png but can't knit it to a dashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, dashboard

I'm trying to knit my rmd file to a dashboard and I can't knit my rmd file because of the following:[image]

The weird thing is that if I run code in the rmd file, my picture is loaded without a problem, as you can see next:

```
img1_path <- "~/Desktop/Dashboard-/Bases/mapa_tratamiento.png"
img1 <- readPNG(img1_path, native =  TRUE, info = TRUE)
attr(img1, "info")
knitr::include_graphics(img1_path)
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, if I run the code in the Rmd, everything works. If I try to knit the rmd to a dashboard, the program isn't able to find the picture.

The same happens if I have this code:

```
knitr::include_graphics("~/Desktop/Dashboard-/Bases/mapa_tratamiento.png")
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Have you  load the packages in the file.  As I said earlier, the package may be loaded in your global env and not in the new env created in knitting

Comment: I have included the packages in the file

Comment: Based on the error, I think it is related to not finding the file i.e. it couldn't access the locatioin specified.  Can you hard code the path i.e remove the `~`

Comment: I removed de ~ and this happened: If I run the code from my rmd my picture gets printed, but does not knit into a dashboard. Now I get this: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

Comment: I meant to get the full path instead of just removing `~`.